# How should we tag questions about the rewrite system?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have <s>four seven</s> 10 tags that can cover the `WP_Rewrite` system:

- [rewrite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite) with 11 questions
- [mod-rewrite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite) with 10 questions
- [htaccess](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htaccess) with 1 questions
- [.htaccess](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess) with 22 question
- [permalinks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permalinks) with 94 questions
- [url](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url) with 21 questions
- [urls](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urls) with 21 questions
- [url-rewriting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url-rewriting) with 53 questions
- [rewrite-rules](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite-rules) with 4 questions
- [rewrite-tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite-tag) with 1 question

I see "the rewrite system" as everything that replaces URLs of the form `/index.php?category=fruit&postname=banana` with *pretty* versions of the form `/fruit/banana/`. So both handling incoming URLs and generating "outgoing" links according to the pretty format can be covered. Incoming URLs can be handled in the `mod_rewrite` configuration of the server (or the equivalent on non-Apache servers), and/or in the `WP::parse_request()` function. The rewrite rules that are used are written using the `WP_Rewrite` class. "Outgoing" URLs are written by `get_permalink()` and friends. All of these functions have filters that allow you to modify every last detail. Getting the rewrite rules correct for an advanced setup (with custom taxonomies or plugins that want their own URLs) can be a difficult task, which is why it is important to collect these questions under the same tag.

[mod-rewrite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite) is not correct, since the rewrites are not always stored in the server config but more and more in WordPress itself.
[htaccess](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htaccess) is actually just a (standardized) file for placing per-directory server configuration, but mostly used for rewrite stuff in WordPress. The convention on other sites is to use [.htaccess](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess).
[permalinks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permalinks) is currently the most used tag, but a *permalink* has a specific meaning in blogging, and most of these probably talk about the subset of *pretty permalinks*, which are implemented via the `WP_Rewrite` system.
[rewrite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite) is maybe the best catch-all name, but almost nobody used it until now, suggesting the "discoverability" of it is low.
[url](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url) and [urls](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urls) should probably be synonyms.
[url-rewriting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url-rewriting) is more popular than just [rewrite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite) - perhaps because people start typing `url` and then see the autocomplete?
[rewrite-rules](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite-rules) and [rewrite-tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite-tag) only cover a part of the whole system, and were not used that much until now.

Any suggestions for cleaning this up?

Comment: @Jan Fabry - You missed *"url"* (11), *"url-rewriting"* (32) and *"urls"* (16).

Comment: @Mike: Thanks, I added them. Even more factions, how am I supposed to get that bronze tag badge!?

Comment: Prepending mod-rewrite and htaccess doesn’t help anyone. Plus, it breaks with the convention on StackOverflow and ServerFault (I’m subscribed to these tags on [stackexchange.com][1]).

URLs may be replaced with URIs to catch the usage of data-URIs. But this is probably needless.


  [1]: http://stackexchange.com

Comment: @toscho: You're right about `[mod-rewrite]` and `[.htaccess]`, I updated my answer.

Comment: @Jan Fabry Strange … did you delete my answer to your suggestions?

Comment: @toscho: No, I thought it would be better as a comment on my answer. I asked a moderator to move it, but it ended up as a comment on the question, not on the answer.

Comment: @Jan Fabry Hm, I’ve written (and seen) it as an answer. Doesn’t matter anymore. What matters is that I didn’t get a notice about the process. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @Jan - Please define Rewrite System. ;)

Comment: @hakre: I added a definition, and I removed your suggestion to vote for `[.htaccess]` as a synonym of `[htaccess]`, because it should be the other way around.

Comment: @Jan - all hard to understand what is synonym for what (probably it's easier on the page to describe what will be replaced with what because a synonym has no direction, a replacement has). Anyway, donkey doh. Please suggest, my rep is not enough for the moment.

Comment: @hakre: It seems my rep is also too low now (maybe it takes some time to recalculate after a retagging?). But that's why we can discuss it on the meta site, then a moderator can force the synonym and do a mass-retagging without us having to do this by hand.

Comment: @Jan - I think for that .htaccess / htaccess point it's pretty clear what to do. Can you poke a mod to just do it for that one so we can lighten the question a bit? With such a long list, we'll never find a solution at once. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be:

- **Use [url-rewriting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url-rewriting) as the main tag for the rewrite system.** Make [rewrite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite), [rewrite-rules](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite-rules) and [rewrite-tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite-tag) synonyms.
- Use [mod-rewrite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite) and [.htaccess](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess) more strictly (and make [htaccess](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htaccess) without the dot a synonym), only when we refer to the server configuration (and consider migrating to Server Fault, which has [very good info](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask) on them)
- Use [permalinks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permalinks) only for actual discussion of "permanent links to an item"
- Use [urls](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urls) (with [url](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url) as a synonym) for stuff like URL shorteners, ...

Older suggestions:

- <s>Replace [mod-rewrite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite) with [apache-mod-rewrite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache-mod-rewrite) or [server-mod-rewrite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server-mod-rewrite), to make clear this is about server configuration (I don't care about `apache` or `server`, this will depend on how this is called in other servers)</s>
- <s>Replace [htaccess](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htaccess) with [apache-htaccess](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache-htaccess) or [server-htaccess](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server-htaccess), for the same reason</s>
- <s>Use [rewrite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite) or [pretty-permalinks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pretty-permalinks) for the rewrite system. I prefer the former because it is technically more correct, but the latter will likely be easier to stumble upon. We could also make one a synonym of the other of course.</s>

Comment: As I could not suggest a synonym .htaccess -> htaccess I just changed it manually. It's only a small iteration but I hope it helps.

Comment: @hakre: I'm sorry I was not clear enough, but I mean that `.htaccess` should be the main tag, and `htaccess` should be a synonym, not the other way around. Thus if you type `htaccess`, you get `.htaccess`. This is [how it is done on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/.htaccess/synonyms) and other sites.

Comment: @Jan - No problem. For htaccess I was able to suggest .htaccess as a tag synonym, please vote: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/htaccess/synonyms

Comment: @hakre: But that would be the other way around, it would make `[htaccess]` the main tag, not `[.htaccess]`, like on other sites.

Comment: More to your answer: I think it's pretty good but the part about permalinks. The term has a specific use in context of WP of which the permalink by definition is only a subset - sort of.

Comment: @hakre: I was not sure about the permalinks myself. Can you write this out in a sort of "definition" (that we could later use for the tag wiki)? It was a good exercise when you asked me to define "the rewrite system"!

Comment: @jan - Permalinks is most often for WP users what was called "pretty" permalinks ([ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks)) which is rewrite. I suggest to convert them into [tag:pretty-permalinks] first and then see if that fits all occasions.

Comment: @hakre: But if they are "pretty permalinks", wouldn't they fall under the rewriting system, and thus be tagged with the outcome of this discussion (`[url-rewriting]` is my favorite now)?

Comment: @Jan - Because I could not answer that question to the full extend, the process of renaming (or better say to  transpose) could clarify that. Some permalinks tagged question might still be left after that and we could still see the full picture because we have not merged into an already existing tag so far (which would destroy the information of origin).