# Should tags use terminology of code or documentation?

Tags: discussion, tags

For example there is higher level organizational name like `Filesystem API` but in code classes and functions use `WP_Filesystem`. Essentially this is same topic.

- tagging with both seems excessive
- formal name is more proper, but often less known/recognizable

Obviously great candidates for synonyms, but what is rule of the thumb which should be master tag?

Opinions?

Answer (score 3):

I would go for the names of the concepts ("documentation terms"), because they can be wider than just the classes used to implement them. The rewriting API is a good example (and [discussed previously](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-should-we-tag-questions-about-the-rewrite-system)): `WP_Rewrite` is just one part of it, there is also the `WP` class that does the actual parsing of the URL. So [url-rewriting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url-rewriting) (to me) is a better tag than [wp-rewrite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp-rewrite).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we can say for certain that either should be the "master" tag because there are many situations where you just can't determine that.  More people recognize `Filesystem API` than `WP_Filesystem` because it's a more common term.  On the other hand, more people recognize `WP_Rewrite` than `URL Rewriting API` because it's a more common term.

I agree that this is a great situation for synonyms, but it should be handled on a case-by-case basis.